# passing paramaters in Javascript function producing unexpected result

Tags: javascript, parameters, event-handling

I have a function where I pass ID parameters as objects into a javascript function but the browser does not pick it up.

```
<div id="searchByUser">
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtSearchByEmail"  onclick="ButtonEnabled('butSearchByEmail', 'txtSearchByEmail')" onkeyup="ButtonEnabled('butSearchByEmail', 'txtSearchByEmail')" />
   <input type="button" runat="server" id="butSearchByEmail" onserverclick="butSearch_Click" value="Search User" disabled/>
</div>
```

if however I do this instead `ButtonEnabled('MainContent_butSearchByEmail', 'MainContent_txtSearchByEmail')` it works fine.

I got this information from the browser(Google Chrome)

Is there a way of doing this without 'hard coding' it like this?

this is the javascript function

```
function ButtonEnabled(objButton, objText) {
    var t = document.getElementById(objText);
    var b = document.getElementById(objButton);
    if (t.value.length > 1) {
        b.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        b.disabled = true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the code of your ButtonEnabled function

Comment: hmmm, normaly it should work like you expected. Are you using frames or something else? Is the id of your element not txtSearchByEmail in your html sourcecode?

Comment: I might me wrong but if you try by passing "document.getElementById(objButton)" instead of b in you condition it should work better

Comment: please ensure that there is only one element with that id in your code

Comment: @VBB that will not make any difference.

Comment: @ben336 Then I'm stuck in C++ dev for too long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you're using asp.net. You have to use `ClientID`

```
<div id="searchByUser">
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtSearchByEmail"  onclick="ButtonEnabled('<%= butSearchByEmail.ClientID %>', '<%= txtSearchByEmail.ClientID %>')" onkeyup="ButtonEnabled('<%= butSearchByEmail.ClientID %>', '<%= txtSearchByEmail.ClientID %>')" />
   <input type="button" runat="server" id="butSearchByEmail" onserverclick="butSearch_Click" value="Search User" disabled/>
</div>
```